# Decrement ngFor loop variable in based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```html
<div class="list-group list-group-flush" *ngFor="let invoice of invoices;index as i">
  <a *ngIf="invoice.name.startsWith('general')" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" [href]="invoice.url" download>General Invoice</a>
  <a *ngIf="invoice.name.startsWith('special')" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" [href]="invoice.url" download> Special Invoice number {{i+1}}</a>
</div>
```

So I want to decrement the index if there is a general invoice so that the index value for special invoice always starts with 1 even if there is a general invoice present. Right now its displaying as 2 if general invoice is there and 1 only if general invoice is not there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pipe to transform your data

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'general'
})
export class GeneralPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(invoices: any[]) {
  let customIndex = 0;
  const checkGeneral = (name) => {
    if (name.startsWith('general')) {
      customIndex = 0;
    }
    if (name.startsWith('special')) {
      customIndex++;
    }
    return customIndex;
  }
  return invoices.map(invoice => ({...invoice, customIndex: checkGeneral(invoice.name) }))
}
}
```

html

```html
<div class="list-group list-group-flush" *ngFor="let invoice of invoices | general">
  <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" [href]="invoice.url" download>
    {{ invoice.name.startsWith('general') ? 'General Invoice' : (' Special invloce ' + invoice.customIndex) }}
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Note: Declare GeneralPipe in your Module